# DNS DKIM setup public key

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim

I am trying to setup DKIM on DNS

## DNS record

```
robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com       IN TXT     "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAu01ErHYuvyzng2KNnd4akmuCdV6nu8oxASIBcORwG8+RpCSdQ+SCcroaj2CwN+sHIayBAodHWIFW4TJzzz26TN+jGXO/P5M2RAgVOOkL0Dz0Cz580f4E+e5fYao4dgYT5FPN+Ny+CJRZRK2/JxpV" "1wY/vE7eb+jzngB1p9vvBKqLgn+9PAUM6dUNOAwYpw7Mg7egWA3N/4J8UDyJ9KV8tHpbiOOOR8lmFUJ88KTZyAKp2Ae9Csv2D3ZbOS12xSDasMf0rlVOua8wQaerEmyN8ssaMTmDUoE8B/HrK2PBma3rek9BMTYy+9yrctaGhuMqAeV6BA8uipQJx3/viTvwAQIDAQAB"
```

When testing mails on http://dkimvalidator.com/ everything seems fine except I get this

```
Public Key DNS Lookup

Building DNS Query for robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com
Retrieved this publickey from DNS: 

Validating Signature

result = invalid
Details: public key: not available
```

It is now several hours since I made the update on the DNS. Maybe there is something wrong with the `IN TXT` record since its not available?!

Comment: Does `robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com.dynaccount.com` exist? You're missing the trailing `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zone files without a terminating period append the domain..

the correct dns record is

```
robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com.       IN TXT     "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAu01ErHYuvyzng2KNnd4akmuCdV6nu8oxASIBcORwG8+RpCSdQ+SCcroaj2CwN+sHIayBAodHWIFW4TJzzz26TN+jGXO/P5M2RAgVOOkL0Dz0Cz580f4E+e5fYao4dgYT5FPN+Ny+CJRZRK2/JxpV" "1wY/vE7eb+jzngB1p9vvBKqLgn+9PAUM6dUNOAwYpw7Mg7egWA3N/4J8UDyJ9KV8tHpbiOOOR8lmFUJ88KTZyAKp2Ae9Csv2D3ZbOS12xSDasMf0rlVOua8wQaerEmyN8ssaMTmDUoE8B/HrK2PBma3rek9BMTYy+9yrctaGhuMqAeV6BA8uipQJx3/viTvwAQIDAQAB"
```

What you have is:

```
dig robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com.dynaccount.com TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4 <<>> robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com.dynaccount.com TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49945
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com.dynaccount.com.        IN TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
robot._domainkey.dynaccount.com.dynaccount.com. 7200 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAu01ErHYuvyzng2KNnd4akmuCdV6nu8oxASIBcORwG8+RpCSdQ+SCcroaj2CwN+sHIayBAodHWIFW4TJzzz26TN+jGXO/P5M2RAgVOOkL0Dz0Cz580f4E+e5fYao4dgYT5FPN+Ny+CJRZRK2/JxpV" "1wY/vE7eb+jzngB1p9vvBKqLgn+9PAUM6dUNOAwYpw7Mg7egWA3N/4J8UDyJ9KV8tHpbiOOOR8lmFUJ88KTZyAKp2Ae9Csv2D3ZbOS12xSDasMf0rlVOua8wQaerEmyN8ssaMTmDUoE8B/HrK2PBma3rek9BMTYy+9yrctaGhuMqAeV6BA8uipQJx3/viTvwAQIDAQAB"

;; Query time: 108 msec
;; SERVER: 10.5.31.9#53(10.5.31.9)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 16 15:53:05 Eastern Daylight Time 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 499
```

Comment: ok.. so it's the same for `_dmarc.dynaccount.com` ?? Either I need to add a trailing period like this `_dmarc.dynaccount.com.` or I need to just create `_dmarc` as a DNS TXT record?

Comment: Either is valid